# Deploy Angular 4 App in windows server

Tags: angular, deployment

I am pretty new to Angular development. I have created an angular 4 application that i want show it to my team. I have an windows 2012 VM server where i want to deploy my application.

1. How many different ways can we deploy Angular 4 apps in Windows server? Please provide details on how to do it.(IIS?)
2. What are steps to follow to have good highly efficient code to run in production?
3. Also how do i do apply continuous deployment for the Angular App.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for when you got GUI access to your windows server I don't know how you can do in CMD anyway :

1-Run `ng build --prod` in your project root (it creates "dist" folder)

2-Then you need a web server. You can install and run [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). Then run apache (it default port is 8080) put "dist" folder in "htdocs" folder in installed XAMPP directory

3-open a browser and go to "localhost:8080/dist"

There is another thing that you can do:

1-Find your system ip address in windows you can find it by running `ipconfig`.

2-Run `ng serve --host 'YOUR_IP_ADDRESS'`

3-Now any one can see your project in "http:YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:4200"

Comment: It's not working for me . While login http://localhost:8080/app/rest/v1/login  , But, my backend is wunning on 8085 port because of this i am get 404 not found error . This was not happening if i was running the app in dev mode because there i had configured the proxy . Please help me    : (